# Developing a C++ Programm with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, licensing

Can I develop a program with Qt in C++ where the user can donate some money if he wants? There will be a little donate button somewhere in the window.

Under which license do I have to publish my program, when I'm using Qt and the user has the opportunity to donate?

A donate program isn't a commercial program, right? So I don't have to buy a Qt License.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Qt is on LGPL license you can make even a commercial, closed source software with it. The only restriction is that if you change something in Qt library you have to publish those changes

Comment: Now that doesn't rectify Niklas' wrong assumption that donations or the term "commercial" have anything to do with the license. Even if Qt wasn't LGPL but GPL, one could write Free Software against it, ask for donations, or sell it for all the money in the world (if you find such a business model :) ). The only requirement would be that the license is GPL-compatible. How much money is involved in the process is completely irrelevant.

Comment: So I must publish the program as a GPL-compatible license, but I can still ask for donations?

Comment: @Niklas No, for LGLP, you have to dynamically link the LGLP library, and you can not change it, without publishing your changes

Comment: Niklas: One can ask for donations for GPL software, sure. Or have someone pay you a million dollars. All you have to do is to provide the source code under the terms of the GPL.